# Enviar 2 variables por POST en Formulario

Tags: php

Estoy generando una tabla con contenido en PHP.
A su vez, el usuario ha de seleccionar 2 datos por filas:
1.- marcar el registro correspondiente con un checkbox
2.- indicar las unidades

```
<?php while ($rowLin = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtLin, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="articulo-<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>" value=''>
                <input type="checkbox" name="articulo-<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>" value='on'>
            </td>
            
            <td><?php echo $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowLin["DescripcionArticulo"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowLin["Partida"]; ?></td>
            <td align="right"><?php echo round($rowLin["Unidades2_"],2); ?></td>
            <td><input type="number" align="right" name="Udsarticulo-<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>" size="3"></td>
          
            <? // Concateno  el id del articulo al nombre del check para poder identificarlo  ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?= $rowLin["CodigoArticulo"]; ?>" name="articulos[]">
       </tr>
   <?php } ?>
```

Hecho esto, en el servidor, recojo los registros marcados con el check, pero no consigo pasar las unidades informadas en el input Udsarticulo

Actualmente en el servidor tengo esto:

```
$articulos = (array)$_POST["articulos"];
```

...

```
foreach( $articulos as $articulo){

        echo "<table>";
        // para hacer referencia al check correcto
        $valor = $_POST["articulo-" . $articulo] == 'on' ? "Si" : "No";
        //echo " Seleccionado:" . $valor;
        if($valor=== 'Si'){
            echo "<TR>";
            echo '<TD width="300">articulo: ' . $articulo . '</TD>';
            echo '<TD><span class="Red">Enviada la Reclamación: ' . $valor . '</span></TD>';
    
        }else{
            echo '<TD  width="300">articulo: ' . $articulo . '</TD>';
            echo "<TD>Enviada la Reclamación:" . $valor . "</TD>";
        }
        echo "<table>";
```

Espero que me podais ayudar.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes imprimir todo lo que llega del POST de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . " -> " . $value;
}
```

Después puedes construir una variable, si recoges de forma correcta $articulos, dentro del foreach:

```
${'Udsarticulo-'.$articulo}
```

Comment: BetaM veo la respuesta editada, veo tachado y después veo lo mismo? ¿Qué no he hecho correctamente?